# NestJs Guard : enable guard on resolverField without error

Tags: security, graphql, nestjs, resolver

i have this ,

```
  @Roles(ROLES.ADMIN)
  @ResolveField('product', () => String)
  async getProduct(@Parent() product: Product) {
    return this.productService.getProduct(product);
  }
```

i already add       `fieldResolverEnhancers: ['guards']`
in appModule
my graphQl request gives me an error

```
     "message": "Forbidden resource",
      "path": [
        "user",
        "product"
      ],
```

witch is the expected behavior
, what i need is that the request succeed  ,but return null as product value if Role !== ADMIN

any suggestions ? thanks